# sql,how to select fields with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

how to choose a field with conditions:
1. not null &
2. id = 1
in the same field?

Comment: you cant have and between them only one exists at a time

Answer (score 1):

```
where id is not null or id=1;  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `IS NOT NULL`

> SELECT column1,column2
>       FROM tablename
>       WHERE id IS NOT      NULL AND id=1;

Answer (score 1):

If you just want records with `id=1`, then the condition `id is NOT NULL` is superflous. You can just write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id = 1;
```

If you want records with `id is NOT NULL` then `id=1` becomes superflous. You can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id is NOT NULL;
```